# Can I Use LocalDB with Local IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I hava visual studio 2015.

I finished my new `asp.net mvc project`, it is using `localdb`.

when I start it with VS 2015 working perfect. (http://localhost:PORT)

I need to start it at `LOCAL IIS`. because of that I installed IIS.

*(Turn Windows features on or off > IIS check > Install)*

Then I created new App under IIS Aplication Default App Pool

After that I publish my project to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject` with Visual Studio.

*(Project > Publish > File System > Local IIS )*

But when publish finished I am getting Database Error.

```
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
```

My ConnectionString like that.

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried a lot of Connection String but nothing change..

Comment: Is this using a named instance of sql server? The \ProjectsV12 is a strange instance name. I would think you Data Source would be more like this. "Data Source=(local);"

Comment: but with this string my project is running with visual studio? In my Visual studio "SQL Server Object Explorer"  tab I have two SQL server. First (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB , second (localdb)\ProjectsV12 . And both of them working when I debuging project with visual studio. My database being created, I see them in my Sql Server Explorer tab. Should I have to install any Microsoft SQL Server? Thanks.